# Does packages from Ubuntu LTS 20.04 work on LTS 22.04?

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, 22.04, vpn

I am planning to upgrade to the Ubuntu version but I wonder if some of the packages I used before won't be compatible with the new version.

I am using it as a business laptop for programming and my biggest concern is the VPN client, I am using FortiClient, and according to their Linux download page, there are no instructions for installation on LTS 22.04:

[FortiClient Linux Download](https://www.fortinet.com/support/product-downloads/linux)

Comment: You'll need to look at its requirements; if it's an open source program (be in Ubuntu, Debian etc) you can look up what those requirements are without it being installed, if it's closed source & only package is provided (*without specifics*), you need a system with it installed to know what is required.  FYI: Some packages will work; eg. a package filled with *wallpapers* will work on any release as it'll have no *depends* requirements, alas this isn't so for more technical packages..

Comment: Forticlient is 3rd party software. You need to ask them that. Or try it out yourself using the live session ;)

Comment: My problem is that my dpkg is messed up and currently I can install nothing, not even balenaEtcher to create bootable device. That is the reason to reinstall my os.

Comment: If you know what you're doing, you can make a rather *accurate* guess as to if you'll have problems or not (ie. *using packages built from one release, on a different release*) as it's pretty easy to guess using open source code (*99% accurate for Ubuntu software*), even for third party (*though accuracy isn't anywhere near as high*), but IF YOU'RE ASKING CAN I, you're more likely to run into problems as you're unlikely to be able to examine the requirements of the package contained within the *depends* etc rules.

Comment: "*My problem is that my dpkg is messed up*" That's the question you should ask about. Asking about your proposed solution instead is a classic [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Whatever caused the "messed up" condition might be much easier to fix.

Answer (score 0):

It's doubtful.

Software packages on Debian-based systems are compiled against a common set of dependencies. One definition of a "new release" is that the common set of dependencies has changed: Versions changed, APIs broken, etc.

Software compiled against one release of Ubuntu (one set of dependencies) is unlikely to work on a different release of Ubuntu (a different set --or versions-- of dependencies).

Indeed, some of the most common help requests come from folks who have attempted to bolt wrong-version software onto their release of Ubuntu...and discovered that it has broken apt and/or the software simply doesn't work anymore. (There's even a [name for it](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian))